# Date format changed in error output text file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, ssis-2005

I have a file to be loaded into SQL Server 2005 using SSIS 2005.

The file has a date field. The values are like `'12/01/2010 16:38:51'`.

Some of the rows in the file are wrong and will be redirected to a text file. But in the text file, the date will be changed to `2010-01-12 16:38:51` by SSIS.

Anyway to just redirect error rows to the text file without any modification?

Comment: SSIS just writes the date the same way the server is configured. Change your regional settings to match the first date format.

Comment: I can't change regional setting. I mean the date format in input file can be of different format. I wouldn't change regional setting to suite the import file. What if the date format change in future? I mean can't ssis just treat the redirected row like a string or something and write it to a file?

Comment: Yes SSIS can treat it as a string, if you define the metadata so. If it changes format, thats because you mapped the input column as date.

Comment: Yeah, I have been playing with that. Like change the input column type to string, etc. But I found the problem is not related to the input column type. Now the input column type is still datebase_timestamp, and the outputed error rows can keep the original date format. I don't know what exactly fixed the problem be cause I have changed lot of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found if the output columns in the flat file error output of advanced editor of the flat file source is 'Flat File Source Error Output Column' (and the type of the column should be text stream [DT_TEXT] by default) then my problem is solved. This way, the flat file manager for the error output will automatically  set the output columns to 'Flat File Source Error Output Column' and of type 'text stream [DT_TEXT]'. This is exactly what I wanted. SSIS treat the whole row as a single column of type 'text stream [DT_TEXT]' and just redirected. And this seems to be the default behaviour of SSIS. But in my original package, I somehow messed up and  let each column from input mapped to a column in the error output. Then there was problem because SSIS was doing the date conversion things.

Anyway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a derived column and format the datetime using the parts of the date.

```
(DT_WSTR, 20) (DT_WSTR, 2) RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(<DATE_IN_QUESTION>),2)  + "/" + 
(DT_WSTR, 2) RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(<DATE_IN_QUESTION>),2) + "/" + 
(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(<DATE_IN_QUESTION>) + " " + 
(DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "Hh", <DATE_IN_QUESTION>) + ":" +  
(DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "mi", <DATE_IN_QUESTION>) + ":" +  
(DT_WSTR, 2) RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "ss", <DATE_IN_QUESTION>),2)
```

Comment: Yeah I know derived column can be used to do whatever format needed. But my question is the redirected rows should keep the original format without any manual effort.